# Как заново подключить библиотеку через require?

Tags: node.js, модули, export, require

Допустим у нас есть **файл 1**

```
[{"a1":1}]
```

И **файл 2**

```
var obj1 = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./файл 1.JSON" , "UTF-8"));
module.exports.obj1 = obj1
```

И мы запускаем программу

```
for(i=0; ; i++) {
  console.log(require('./файл 2').a1);
  let bb = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./файл 1.JSON" , "UTF-8"));
  console.log(bb.a1);
  (тут еще пауза, чтобы цикл был замедленн)
}
```

И в это время отредактируем **файл 1**, заменив значение на другое число.
Тогда тот участок программы, который показывает через **require** покажет старое значение, а через **fs** новое значение.

Теперь вопрос, *как сделать так, чтобы require показал новое значение*?

Comment: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23685930/clearing-require-cache), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666144/how-to-remove-module-after-require-in-node-js). [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210542/node-js-require-cache-possible-to-invalidate)

Comment: файл 1 - библиотека с кодом или файл с данными?

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо сделать:

```
function f() {
 return JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./файл 1.JSON" , "UTF-8"))
}
module.exports.f = f
```

Comment: Рома, перегрузкой библиотеки называется совсем другой сценарий. Переименуйте вопрос, чтобы он лучше соответствовал своему содержанию и чтобы другие не путались